# VBA error Invalid Use of Property

Tags: excel, vba

this has definitely been asked for but I'm not sure how the answers were applicable to my problem and so it remains unresolved. I'm looking to call certain codes when I click on a certain spreadsheet and have been able to do it until I included a fourth, new code. Now when I click on Sheet 2, the sheet with the code below, it highlights Sub Worksheet_Activate() and displays Invalid Use of Property.

```
Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Call VBAProject.Module1.ComplexCopyPust
Call VBAProject.Module2.ComplexCopyPust
Call SetPrintArea
Call Sort

End Sub
```

I only added the Call Sort. It worked with all the other codes beforehand.

Call Sort code below. I used record macro to create it.

```
Sub Sort()
'
' SortNumberLetter Macro
'

 On Error Resume Next
 'Finds last row of content
  ALastFundRow = Columns("C").Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, 
  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues).Row


  '
On Error Resume Next
Range("A8:Q" & ALastFundRow).Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-462
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WIRE SCHEDULE").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WIRE SCHEDULE").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "A8:A" & ALastFundRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortTextAsNumbers
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WIRE SCHEDULE").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "C8:C" & ALastFundRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WIRE SCHEDULE").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A8:Q" & ALastFundRow)
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

Anything helps!

Comment: Step 1 in debugging: get rid of `On Error Resume Next`. You shouldn't use it as `On Error Hide Bug` (which is how you are using it). It is truly a bad habit in VBA programming. Don't silence errors -- *handle* them.

Comment: @JohnColeman I only include this because sometimes the sheet will blank as we use it as a template. And its annoying to have to click ignore every time we open up a new workbook to start work. But I'll take note when making new code. I'm very new to this so I'm trying to hang on to as much as I can.

Comment: `Range.Find` returns `Nothing` if it doesn't find anything - that will make the chained `.Row` call fail with run-time error 91, and you can very easily avoid that error, instead of ignoring it and happily continuing execution. Rule of thumb, as a rookie if you type `On Error Resume Next`, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: When you drop those lines -- what error message appears and with what lines? There *is* a disciplined way to use `On Error Resume Next` -- put it before a statement which might throw an error, then test if `Err.Number <> 0` (and, if so, handle it and use `Err.Clear` to clear the error) and then, finally, have `On Error GoTo 0` to turn off `On Error Resume Next`.

Comment: @JohnColeman it still directs to the sheet 2 stating Invalid Use of Property. The code for sorting works regardless of whether or not I include the On error resume next as it runs and does its job when I run it individually. The issue is when I click on sheet 2, the sheet with Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Call VBAProject.Module1.ComplexCopyPust
Call VBAProject.Module2.ComplexCopyPust
Call SetPrintArea
Call Sort

End Sub 

it doesn't execute all 4 modules. It can run the first three just fine if it's just those four, but when I add the fourth it gives me invalid use of property.

Comment: Exactly which line throws the error? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @Mat'sMug sorry, Sub Worksheet_Activate() is highlighted yellow and displays the error.

Comment: @Mat'sMug just did.

Comment: Go to tools > options, and verify that error handling is set to "break on all errors". I don't think an event handler procedure's signature is the real cause of the problem.

Comment: @Mat'sMug okay so I did that and it still highlights 
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate() yellow
however, it now also highlights Call Sort () blue.

Comment: @jsotola it ends up just working as a comment, the code isn't executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either qualify `Sort` with the module name that it is in (e.g. `VBAProject.Module1.Sort`), or not use `Sort` as the name of the subroutine (because VBA is confusing it with the `Sort` property of the sheet that the code is associated with).

I would *strongly* recommend changing the subroutine name.  (Perhaps change the subroutine name from `Sort` to `SortNumberLetter`.)